# responsive divs stack order

Tags: html, css

thanks in advance for your help.

4 divs in a row, inside a container DIV ( max-width: 800px )
DIV1 - float left, fixed width ( 250px )
DIV2 - float left, fixed width ( 200px )
DIV3 - no float (min-width:200px) - taking the rest of row witdh
DIV4 - float right, fixed width ( 50px )

[4 divs in a row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrzUX.png)

I need the design to be responsive and as the window resizes,
 
the divs must stack vertically, in the order showed in 
picture 'divs stack order' bellow.
Please, note that div3 is not fixed width.

[divs stack order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBEUh.png)

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

> "order" property only works in   "Display:flex" property

```css
#main {
    max-width: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#main div {
     height: 80px;
     margin: 1px;
     font-size: 50px;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 20px;
}
#div1 {
     background-color: yellow;
     width: 250px;
     order: 1;
}
#div2 {
     background-color: lightblue;
     width: 200px;
     order: 2;
}
#div3 {
     background-color: lightgreen;
     min-width: 200px;
     order: 3;
}
#div4 {
     background-color: pink;
     width: 50px;
     order: 4;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 730px) {
       #div1 {
            width: 44%;
       }
       #div2 {
             background-color: lightblue;
             width: 40%;
             order: 2;
       }
       #div3 {
             width: 100%;
             order: 4;
       }
       #div4 {
             width: 15%;
             order: 3;
       }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
       #div1 {
            width: 70%;
       }
       #div2 {
            width: 100%;
            order: 3;
       }
       #div3 {
             width: 100%;
             order: 4;
       }
       #div4 {
             width: 29%;
             order: 2;
       }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
       #div1 {
            width: 100%;
        }
        #div2 {
             width: 100%;
             order: 3;
        }
        #div3 {
             width: 100%;
             order: 4;
        }
        #div4 {
             width: 100%;
             order: 2;
        }
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
   <div id="div1">1</div>
   <div id="div2">2</div>
   <div id="div3">3</div>
   <div id="div4">4</div>
</div>
```